# triggering jquery after x height was scrolled

Tags: jquery, css

I want jQuery to change the color of the navigation background once the user scrolls past certain height. Here is my existing snippet.

```
var elementPosition = $('.home-menu').offset();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
         $('.pure-menu-open').css('background','#222');
    } else {
         $('.pure-menu-open').css('background','#fff');
    }    
});
```

But it changes color to `#222` after about `50px - 100px` scroll.

Comment: Jsfiddle.net please -

Answer (score 0):

What your script is saying is, if the scrollTop value is greater than the distance of the .home-menu from the top of the page, then change the background colour. However what I think you want it to say is, if the scrollTop value is greater than the offset plus the height of the element, then change the colour.

So I would suggest adding the height of the element to the statement. If for example the height of the element is 200px:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top + 200){
```

Your other option is to test for a specific value:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > 40){
```

Here's a demo codepen where I add the height programatically - http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/cbBCk

And an article for further reading - http://iwearshorts.com/blog/measuring-user-scroll-with-jquery/